# How to filter JSON data according to specified parameter AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have external JSON file call datas. This is the body of that JSON file.

```
[
    {"value": "1", "text": "aaa"},
    {"value": "2", "text": "bbb"},
    {"value": "3", "text": "ccc"},
    {"value": "4", "text": "ddd"},
    {"value": "5", "text": "eee"},
    {"value": "6", "text": "fff"},
    {"value": "7", "text": "ggg"},
    {"value": "8", "text": "hhh"},
    {"value": "9", "text": "iii"},
    {"value": "10", "text": "jjj"}
]
```

I want to filter data from this JSON file according to following array "b" values.(b0, b1, b3 etc)

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,5,7","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"5","b3":"7"}
```

Example:

This array have b0, b1, b2 and b3 those values are 1, 2, 5 and 7. Therefor I want to get only 1, 2, 5, 7 values arrays from datas JSON file and display text values of this array.

This array can be change with same format. Therefor I want to consider b+"number" parameters.

Example 1:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,3,9","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"3","b3":"9"}
```

Example 2:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,7","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"7"}
```

Example 3:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,5,7,8,9","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"5","b3":"7","b4":"8","b5":"9"}
```

I get that JSON external file using angularjs like this,

```
$http.get("/json/datas.json").success(function(data) {
      $scope.datas= data;
});
```

Values are display using repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <span ng-bind-html="data.text"></span>
</div>
```

Display HTML body only

aaa
bbb
eee
ggg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript prototype functions `map` and `find` to filter the data.
First get the batch properties to an array and map the array to find the relevant values

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,3,9","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"3","b3":"9"}
var batchArr = $scope.array.badge.split(',');
$scope.result = batchArr.map(o=> $scope.datas.find(k=> k.value == o))
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$sce){
$scope.datas = [
    {"value": "1", "text": "aaa"},
    {"value": "2", "text": "bbb"},
    {"value": "3", "text": "ccc"},
    {"value": "4", "text": "ddd"},
    {"value": "5", "text": "eee"},
    {"value": "6", "text": "fff"},
    {"value": "7", "text": "ggg"},
    {"value": "8", "text": "hhh"},
    {"value": "9", "text": "iii"},
    {"value": "10", "text": "jjj"}
]
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,3,9","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"3","b3":"9"}

var batchArr = $scope.array.badge.split(',');
$scope.result = batchArr.map(o=> $scope.datas.find(k=> k.value == o)) 


console.log($scope.result)

$scope.trust = function(html){
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="data in result">
    <span ng-bind-html="trust(data.text)"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hey personally not a fan of a jsfiddle. created a plnkr though https://plnkr.co/edit/oag45U7BA2rQMxCIhirr?p=preview

Comment: Can you explane me o=> $scope.datas.find(k=> k.value == o) this. Why do you get o and k. Can we use any latter?

Comment: these are ES6 syntax for function references if you are using ES5 then use this  `$scope.result = batchArr.map(function(o) {
 return $scope.datas.find(function(k) {
  return k.value == ol
 })
})`

Comment: `map` and `find` are prototype functions which iterates through a given array . `o` and `k` is the relevant object of that iterating array

Comment: o=> $scope.datas.find(k=> k.value == o) code is not working in EI

Comment: browse must support es6 in order work it. use this `batchArr.map(function(o){ return $scope.datas.find(function(k){return  k.value == o})})`

Comment: I get IE error in console. TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Comment: For find method browser support starts from IE 12.

Comment: How to do it older browsers?

Comment: can you explane me more in code. Can't we use filter ?

Comment: in order to write the filter you need to manually write the logic

Comment: first loop the batcharr then inside it loop the datas array then use if condition to check `k.value == o` and if its true return the batcharr object

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to filter, map, and/or reduce the array that has the `"bX"` values to create a lookup table of IDs, then filter the main `data` array based on that lookup table. Except that that "array" isn't an array, it is a plain object, so you can't use array methods on it directly. So I'm calling `Object.keys()` to get its keys in an array, and then I've chosen to use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the lookup table based on the keys that have the right format:

```js
var data = [ {"value": "1", "text": "aaa"}, {"value": "2", "text": "bbb"}, {"value": "3", "text": "ccc"}, {"value": "4", "text": "ddd"}, {"value": "5", "text": "eee"}, {"value": "6", "text": "fff"}, {"value": "7", "text": "ggg"}, {"value": "8", "text": "hhh"}, {"value": "9", "text": "iii"}, {"value": "10", "text": "jjj"} ]

var $scope = {} // demo $scope object
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,5,7","id":"0","b0":"1","b1":"2","b2":"5","b3":"7"}

var bVals = Object.keys($scope.array).reduce(function(a, c) {
    if (/^b\d+$/.test(c))
      a[$scope.array[c]] = true
    return a
  }, {})
  
console.log(bVals)

var filteredData = data.filter(function(v) { return bVals[v.value] })

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that the `badge` property had the same information as the individual `bX` properties. That would've simplified my code. Oh well.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah i just saw it half way trough :D

Comment: @Hey - Why?  The code snippet in my answer can be run directly from this page, so you can see it works.